# Post list from Thymeleaf to spring controller

Tags: spring, thymeleaf

I am trying to write some code to pass a list of items, say ids, from a thymeleaf form to spring controller so that I update only those records that are selected. I am able to do the selection but not posting. I have tried most of the things online but no success. Any help will be appreciated.

Thymeleaf Code

```
<form th:action="@{/invoicing/processInvoices/updateInvoice}" th:object="${invoiceDetails}" method="POST"  >
            <div >
                <h4>Process Invoice</h4>
            </div>


            <fieldset>
                <legend>Document Entries</legend>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="form-group col-sm-8">
                        <table border="1" th:id="invoiceTable" th:name="invoiceTable">
                            <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>No</th>
                                <th>ID No</th>
<!--                                <th>Invoice No.</th>-->
                                <th>Student Name</th>
                                <th>Invoice Desc</th>
                                <th>Total</th>
                                <th>Status</th>
                               <th>Approvals/ <br/>
                                    <input th:type="checkbox" th:id="checkAll" th:name="checkAll"  onclick="selectAllCheckBox();"/>Sellect All
                                </th>
                                <!--<th> Action</th>-->
                            </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                            <tr class="col-sm-auto" th:each="invo : ${invoice}" th:size="100px">
                                <td th:text="${invoStat.count}"></td>
                                <td th:text="${invo.id}" th:hidden="hidden" th:name="id" th:id="id"></td>
                                <td th:text="${invo.docNumber}"></td>
                                <td th:text="${invo.studentNumber}"></td>
                                <td th:text="${invo.documentDescription}"></td>
                                <td th:text="${invo.amount}"></td>
                                <td th:text="${invo.status}"></td>
                                <td><input type="checkbox" th:name="approval" th:id="approval" /></td>
                                <!--<td><a th:href="@{'/invoicing/processInvoices/updateInvoice/{id}'(id=${invo.id})}">
                                    <button class="btn btn-sm btn-success"><span class="fa fa-edit">
                                    </span>Verify</button>
                                </a> </td>-->
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td colspan="4" ><b>Total</b></td>
                                <td colspan="2" th:text="${total}"></td>
                                <td colspan="2"></td>
                            </tr>
                            </tbody>
                            <tfoot>

                            </tfoot>
                           <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" th:id="updateRecord" th:name="updateRecord">Verify</button>
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-warning">Clear</button>
                        </table>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </fieldset>

        </form>
      <script type="text/javascript">
            $(function () {
                //Assign Click event to Button.
                $("#updateRecord").click(function () {
                    var message = "";
                    var x= [];

                    //Loop through all checked CheckBoxes in GridView.
                    $("#invoiceTable input[type=checkbox]:checked").each(function () {
                        var row = $(this).closest("tr")[0];
                        var id = $(this).closest("tr")[0];
                        message += row.cells[1].innerHTML;
                       /* message += "   " + row.cells[2].innerHTML;
                        message += "   " + row.cells[3].innerHTML;*/
                        message += "\n";
                        x.push(message);

                    });
                    $.ajax({
                        url:"/invoicing/processInvoices/updateInvoice",
                        type:"POST",
                        data:x,
                        contentType:"application/json; charset=utf-8",
                        dataType:"json",
                    //Display selected Row data in Alert Box.
                     //alert(message);
                    alert(x);


                     //alert(id);

                });
            });
        </script>
    </div>

Controller
  @RequestMapping(path = "updateInvoice", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    @ResponseBody
    public String updateInvoice(@RequestParam  List<Long> id, Model model){

    System.out.println(id);
```

Sample print out
[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to correctly bind checkbox to the object list in thymeleaf?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39424715/how-to-correctly-bind-checkbox-to-the-object-list-in-thymeleaf)

Comment: your `alert(x)` is in wrong brackets, also missing closing brackets for `$(function () {` check browser console you should see errors there fix them.

Comment: @vicpermir, thanks for that. Let me check it out.

Comment: @Augustas, edit for me where possible. I have been on this thing for the past two weeks.I appreciate