# How to get forms values from HTTP-request in controller?

Tags: java, html, spring-mvc, checkbox, thymeleaf

How can I pass list from my HTML checkbox form to controller which processes that list?

[image: illustration of issue]

Comment: Guessing from @PostMapping annotation, Is this a Spring Boot application?

Comment: yes, that is Spring Boot App

Comment: Your question seems similar to https://stackoverflow.com/a/40376756/40064 Have you looked into this answer?